# Adding forigen key relationships constraint to table from field naming convention

Tags: mysql, database

In a `MySQL` database I have large amount of tables. there is not any foreign key relationships constraint but it could be done.

In my tables the foreign key field name and its equivalent primary key field both are the same.

I can guess the relations from this, but I want to add constraint to tables according to this convention.

is there any tool to do this? or may I write a script to do?